# Mysql statement, if at least one row contains result

Tags: mysql, select

i've a table with records:

```
----------------------------------
ID   |  UniqueId |  Name  | Result
----------------------------------
1       1           Test1   OK
2       1           Test1   Cancelled
3       1           Test1   OK
4       2           Test2   OK
5       2           Test2   OK
6       2           Test2   OK
7       2           Test2   OK
8       3           Test3   OK
9       3           Test3   OK
```

Let's say i wan't to check if at least one row with UniqueId = 1 not contains Result == Cancelled. To exclude record with UniqueId = 1, because it is cancelled.
How can i do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.* from table as t1 where t1.UniqueId not in(select t.UniqueId from table as t 
where t.Result="Cancelled")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE uniqueId = 1 AND result != 'Cancelled'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ask for rows with `UniqueId = 1` and `Result != Cancelled`

```
SELECT ID FROM table WHERE UniqueId = 1 AND Result <> 'Cancelled' LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go this way, but the other answers are a bit easier in terms of syntax.

```
SELECT UniqueId, Name
FROM Table T
GROUP BY UniqueId, Name
HAVING Result != 'Cancelled'
```